# Can I change my Skype status on a Lumia 950?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, skype

Since Skype is now integrated tightly with the OS I'm experiencing a few annoyances.

First of all, I use Skype for work IM and have a lot of conversations. It's all but burying my text message notifications meaning I often miss them.

Second, I appear to be online 24 hours a day and I can't find any way of changing this. Does anybody know if there's some setting where I can change that?

I've always loved Windows Phones but while convenient in someways this new Skype integration is driving me kinda crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the skype integration in the messaging app and use the standalone Skype Application (to not mess around with your text messages, for your n°1 problem), in which you can choose to appear online or, as said above by @Aventinus, invisible. (for your N°2 problem).

To avoid using the built in Skype tools sign out by going to Settings inside of the Skype Video app.

Comment: The question was more about how to disable it. I did finally find the sign out option under the Skype Video app but forgot to circle back here.

Answer (score 1):

Skype integration has always been disappointing in every mobile OS. Unfortunately the only option in terms of status is choosing between **Online** and **Invisible**. Switching to Invisible may save you from some of the spam.

However, there *should be* a **Sign Out** option. (I have currently migrated back to 8.1 so I can't check).

There's a **final solution** to this problem which is not elegant at all but alas. Make a new Skype account and for the hours that you don't want to receive any messages, log in with this account.